# OpenVPN routing issue (cache in routing tables)

Tags: windows, routing, openvpn

I'm adding the `route IP_ADDRESS NETMASK net_gateway`to the OpenVPN config file (locally), so it's not being pushed by the server and it works perfectly fine.

However, when I **remove** the routing line from the configuration file and reconnect to the OpenVPN server, it stays in the routing tables (according to `route PRINT` (in cmd.exe) on Windows 7). Which means OpenVPN doesn't remove the previously generated route.

I'd like to know how to prevent this. I have added a sample configuration file below (which is not too special).

```
client
dev tap
proto tcp-client
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass
route 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 7 client machine is most likely caching the IP entry in it's ARP table or routing table. This Microsoft article outlines some default ARP behavior on Windows 7 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949589, including what the default time an entry is retained for. To test this hypothesis, I would connect using OpenVPN, disconnect, then flush the ARP table, and/or flush the routing table as well and see if the route still persists. If it's immediately gone, see how long it takes Windows 7 to remove the route without the manual flush. If that is the case, then you'll have to find a way to modify the default lifetime of a route/arp entry either via OpenVPN or a Windows 7 parameter or flush the table on the client post OpenVPN disconnect.

Comment: As far as I could test, the route is persistant until the next reboot or when the network device is restarted (disable and re-enable). Currently I have found a solution (but it's in `C#`) so it's not relevant to my initial question.

Comment: @Devator i am also using C# please let me know the solution.

Comment: @ShreyansShrivastav Pff, I've looked back at the old source code. From the looks of it, I simply ran `route delete` for each route created previously. This is not a failsafe solution (e.g. when the app crashes) and I would look into other options. Maybe there's OpenVPN hooks or anything you could use (like I said, long time ago I used this solution). Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Define re-connect?  How are you reconnecting?

You are using `persist-tun` in your configuration, which means the tunnel device stays up during a standard reload.  Since the interface never goes down, routes associated with it never go away.

Comment: Reconnect: killing openvpn.exe en starting a new instance. I've removed `persist-tun` from the configuration file but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set up DHCP server and push routes using it:
   https://superuser.com/questions/874671/how-can-i-inform-mac-os-and-ios-clients-of-vpn-routes
2. Remove `persist-tun` and pushing IP to client in VPN server configuration file.

I have this setup in a company I take care about, works perfectly. Basic idea of this solution is that Windows will deconfigure VPN interface after disconnect and configure it again after successful connect. No need for administrator rights, no hidden agenda, it's just work. Compatibility? Everything besides MacOS.